# gazebo joint effort accumulation

Tags: ros, gazebo, controller-manager, joint-states

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

According to [this](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Communication_with_Gazebo) all active efforts applied to the same joint are cumulative.

However, why don't I see the effort field of joint_states message, which is published by controller_manager, gets accumulated ? It only shows the last applied effort.

I use the following command.

```
rosservice call /gazebo/apply_joint_effort '{joint_name: "joint1", effort: 1.0, start_time: 0, duration: -1}'
```

I use ROS Hydro with Gazebo 1.9

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154611/gazebo-joint-effort-accumulation/) by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 387 on 2014-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Referring to the doc of [gazebo::physics::Joint::SetForce(...)](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Joint.html#a1eb00145de3a61aaa0ee7506a6ab44c2)

> Force is additive (multiple calls to SetForce to the same joint in the same time step will accumulate forces on that Joint).

Notice the **same time step** part. If you're using te ROS service API multiple times, you won't see the additive effect, as different service requests are likely processed in different timesteps.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2014-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2014-04-28**:
Also, you'll probably get faster answers to Gazebo-specific questions if you ask them in answers.gazebosim.org

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that this issue is known since quite some time, see [Bitbucket Gazebo Ticket 878](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/878/joint-setforce-documentation-incomplete) and tickets referenced therein. Your specific issue appears to be tracked already in [issue 485](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/485/update-joint-getforce-to-return).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1